# android - creating a score count

Tags: java, android

I try to make a game and I need to count the score. The score is generated in the `load()` method and should be put at TextView `score`. The problem that comes up is, that my textView is not changing, it always stays the same: `0`.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    public int sco = 0;
    public int colora;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        load();

        TextView score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        score.setText(String.valueOf(sco));
    }

    private void load() {

        Bitmap bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bg);
        RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rect);
        ll.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bg));

        List < Integer > numbers = Arrays.asList(Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW);
        Collections.shuffle(numbers);

        colora = numbers.get(0);
        if (colora == Color.RED) {
            sco++;
        }

        paint.setColor(numbers.get(0));
        canvas.drawRect(20, 15, 11, 3, paint);

        paint.setColor(numbers.get(1));
        canvas.drawRect(19, 15, 15, 3, paint);

        paint.setColor(numbers.get(2));
        canvas.drawRect(5, 5, 15, 35, paint);

        paint.setColor(numbers.get(3));
        canvas.drawRect(5, 15, 26, 1.4, paint);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call `score.setText(String.valueOf(sco));` every time `sco` changes. You are only calling it once in `onCreate()`.

Answer (score 1):

I would move a copy of this:

```
score.setText(String.valueOf(sco));
```

into your load method:

```
    colora = numbers.get(0);
    if (colora == Color.RED) {
        sco++;
        score.setText(String.valueOf(sco));
    }
```

so everything together would be:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnGestureListener {
    private Paint paint = new Paint();
    public int sco = 0;
    public int colora;
    TextView score;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);

        score = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        score.setText(String.valueOf(sco));

        load();
    }

    private void load() {

        Bitmap bg = Bitmap.createBitmap(480, 800, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bg);
        RelativeLayout ll = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.rect);
        ll.setBackgroundDrawable(new BitmapDrawable(bg));

        List < Integer > numbers = Arrays.asList(Color.RED, Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.YELLOW);
        Collections.shuffle(numbers);

        colora = numbers.get(0);
        if (colora == Color.RED) {
            sco++;
            score.setText(String.valueOf(sco));
        }

        paint.setColor(numbers.get(0));
        canvas.drawRect(20, 15, 11, 3, paint);

        paint.setColor(numbers.get(1));
        canvas.drawRect(19, 15, 15, 3, paint);

        paint.setColor(numbers.get(2));
        canvas.drawRect(5, 5, 15, 35, paint);

        paint.setColor(numbers.get(3));
        canvas.drawRect(5, 15, 26, 1.4, paint);
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, it starts counting, but not continually. It even increases when the condition is not true? Or is the shuffle method not very precise?

Comment: I would check your code around it. Use your debugger to determine what code is being passed into the if statement.

Comment: How do I use it to see that?

Comment: You set a break point, and then view the value when you step through the condition. If you're not sure how to use the debugger, you should Google it and learn. Very helpful.

Comment: Okay, I tried it. The only thing I figured out is, that my `colora` varaible changed from 0 to -16711936, that looks a little suspicious I think?

Comment: No, not if you know how colors work. It's very possible a negative number could represent a color.

Comment: So should the condition be `if(colora == -16711936`, then?

Comment: No, you should be able to reference the enum

Comment: How do I get the enum?